# Using Parallel For Loop in Python to Calculate Median Given Window Size

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm trying to calculate the medians of an array given a window (similar to sliding window - reference the test case I use which I also post the correct output too). I want to make my for loop parallel but it is not working. I think it is most likely because I am using i and referencing future indices of the input. I am not sure how to fix this.

```
def smooth_data(data_arr, window_size):
    smoothed_data_arr = [0] * (len(data_arr) - window_size + 1)
    for i in range(0, len(smoothed_data_arr)):
        smoothed_data_arr[i] = round(np.median(data_arr[i:i + window_size]), 1)    
    return smoothed_data_arr
```

Below is a test that I use to see if it is working as intended

```
data_arr = np.array([6,7,2,3,4,5,8,8,3,8,6,4,2,5])
window_size = 3
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = [pool.apply(smooth_data, args=(data_arr, window_size)) for i in data_arr]
pool.close()
print(results)
```

Correct output:  `[6.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 6.0, 6.0, 4.0, 4.0]`
So far when I run it, it doesn't output anything (maybe it's running forever?).

Comment: You hard-wire the window size. It would seem better to let it depend on the `cpu_count`.

Comment: What do you mean? The window_size needs to be a set number since the user may want it to be a specific value.

Comment: Yes. I misread.